# Función eliminar espacios en blanco

Tags: javascript

estoy buscando la forma de eliminar los espacios en blanco de un input

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="cardNumber" data-checkout="cardNumber" placeholder="Número de tarjeta">
```

Este input lo manejo con Javascript de la siguiente manera:

```
<script>
function setCardNetwork()
{
    const cardNumber = document.getElementById("cardNumber");
    mercadoPago.getPaymentMethod(
        { "bin": cardNumber.value.substring(0,6) },
        function(status, response) {
            const cardNetwork = document.getElementById("cardNetwork");
            cardNetwork.value = response[0].id;
        }
    );
}
```

Probé algunas formas y no me funciona.

Por ejemplo:

```
  const cardNetwork = document.getElementById("cardNetwork").replace(/\s/g, "");
```

Agradezco mucho una idea de como puedo hacer esto.

Answer (score 1):

El único problema que veo es que estás aplicando la función *replace* sobre un objeto del DOM, cuando debes aplicarla sobre un *string*:

```js
var input = document.getElementById("cardNetwork");
var valor = input.value;

var new_valor = valor.replace(/\s/g, "");
input.value = new_valor;
```

```html
<input type="text" id="cardNetwork" value=" hola adios "/>
```

Comment: Agradezco mucho tu ayuda, entiendo que es una funcionalidad que funciona la que me indicas, el problema es que no encuentro como hacer que funcione en mi código.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que no sabes cuantos espacios va a ingresar el usuario. Es decir puede que haya un espacio "x"  2 espacios "xx"  o más pero no se sabe por esa razón le recomiendo la siguiente solución:

```html
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="cardNumber" data-checkout="cardNumber" placeholder="Número de tarjeta">

<button id="probar">Test</button>

<script>
 const cardNumber = document.getElementById("cardNumber");
  const submit = document.getElementById("probar");
  
  
function eliminarBlancos(text)
{
    let hayBlanco=true;
    
    while(hayBlanco){
      if(text.includes(' ')){
        text=text.replace(' ','');
      }else{
        hayBlanco=false;
      }
    }
    return text;
   
}


submit.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{

e.preventDefault();


let sinBlancos=eliminarBlancos(cardNumber.value);
console.log(sinBlancos);
});


</script>
```